# How Should I Parsing Json In Array In Array

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, retrofit

I was trying to parse Json in array in array But It doesn't worked.
Source was like this

```
    @POST("/storyGet")
fun getStory() : Call<ArrayList<StoryData>>
```

this is API.kt's and

```
Client.retrofitService.getStory().enqueue(object :
        retrofit2.Callback<ArrayList<StoryData>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<StoryData>>?, response: Response<ArrayList<StoryData>>?) {
            val repo = response!!.body()
            when (response.code()) {
                200 -> {
                    repo!!.indices.forEach {
                        items += StoryDataSubListItem(
                                repo[it][it][it].alreadyWatch,
                                repo[it][it][it].createdAt,
                                repo[it][it][it].imgUrl,
                                repo[it][it][it].storyUUID,
                                repo[it][it][it].userName,
                                repo[it][it][it].userName,
                                repo[it][it][it].userUUID
                            )
                        recyclerView!!.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<StoryData>>?, t: Throwable?) {
        }
    })
```

This is my Retrofit Data and

```
class StoryData : ArrayList<StoryDataSubList>()
```

this is first Array and

```
class StoryDataSubList : ArrayList<StoryDataSubListItem>()
```

this is my second array and

```
data class StoryDataSubListItem(
val alreadyWatch: List<Any>,
val createdAt: String,
val imgUrl: String,
val storyUUID: String,
val userName: String,
val userProfileImgUrl: String,
val userUUID: String)
```

this is dataclass and json in array in array's format is

```
[
[
    {
        "alreadyWatch": [],
        "createdAt": "test",
        "_id": "_id",
        "userUUID": "userUUID2",
        "userName": "userName2",
        "userProfileImgUrl": "false",
        "imgUrl": "imageUrl",
        "storyUUID": "StoryUUID",
        "__v": 0
    }
],
[
    {
        "alreadyWatch": [],
        "createdAt": "test",
        "_id": "_id",
        "userUUID": "userUUID",
        "userName": "TEST NAME",
        "userProfileImgUrl": "false",
        "imgUrl": "imageURL",
        "storyUUID": "StoryUUID",
        "__v": 0
    }
]]
```

When I saw logcat, server was in normal operation
when like this how should I fix It? please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Is response.body() not null? check it and where you set list to the adapter?

Comment: when I see logcat when response code is 200 it always return json

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as below, since the response has list of another list of the given model data,

```
 @POST("/storyGet")
 fun getStory() : Call<List<List<StoryDataSubList>>>
```

Full code is as below

```
@POST("/storyGet")
     fun getStory() : Call<List<List<StoryDataSubList>>>
```

method calling retrofit API to get the response as below

```
private fun loadStoryData() {
            val call = netWorkApi.getStory() // replace netWorkApi with your retrofit API sevice
    
            call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<List<StoryDataSubList>>> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<List<StoryDataSubList>>>,
                    response: Response<List<List<StoryDataSubList>>>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        for (index in response.body()?.indices!!)
                            Log.d("TAG", "${response.body()!!.get(index)}")
    
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<List<StoryDataSubList>>>, t: Throwable) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            });
    
        }
```

Comment: sorry when i copied this source and insert but it dosen't worked 
server was worked normal operation and it return json...

Comment: Oh When I changed StoryDatSubList To data class it worked! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ArrayList` with `List` and try it.

Comment: abstract class StoryData : List<StoryDataSubList>
like this I Changed all ArrayList To List but it was not worked

Comment: abstract?!! You should use data class for all model class.

Comment: when 200 ok response is come and noting is happend even no errors..